# Javascript "removeEventListener" not working

Tags: javascript

I've tried troubleshooting my code using console.log and seeing if it will run, but it seems like it just bypasses the the removeEventListeners. I've had peers check my code and not understand what the problem is.
Javascript:

```
function useCodelock(){
if (one == 1 && nine == 1 && five == 1 & seven == 1 && two == 1 && ninetwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("main-view").style.backgroundImage="url('images/gray.png')";
    document.getElementById("1").removeEventListener("click", removeImg);
    document.getElementById("6").removeEventListener("click", removeImg);
    document.getElementById("9").removeEventListener("click", removeImg);
    document.getElementById("12").removeEventListener("click", removeImg);
    document.getElementById("14").removeEventListener("click", removeImg);
    document.getElementById("21").removeEventListener("click", removeImg);
    document.getElementById("34").removeEventListener("click", removeImg);
    document.removeEventListener("click", removeImg);
}else{
    alert("You Must Find The Code To Use The Lock.");
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-view-cont">
        <div class="main-view" id="main-view">
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="" id="1" onclick="removeImg(this)" class="opacity25"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="images/9.png" id="6" onclick="removeImg(this)" class="opacity25"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="images/5.png" id="9" onclick="removeImg(this)" class="opacity25"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="" id="12" onclick="removeImg(this)" class="opacity25"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="images/keypad.png" id="14" onclick="useCodelock()"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="" id="21" onclick="removeImg(this)" class="opacity25"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="" id="34" onclick="removeImg(this)" class="opacity25"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item2"><img src="" id="i1" class="opacity1"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item2"><img src="" id="i2" class="opacity1"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item2"><img src="" id="i3" class="opacity1"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item2"><img src="" id="i4" class="opacity1"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item2"><img src="" id="i5" class="opacity1"/></div>
            <div class="grid-item2"><img src="" id="i6" class="opacity1"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeEventListener` can only remove listeners that were added with `addEventListener`. If you use `onclick` attributes, you need to assign to that property.

```
function useCodelock() {
  if (one == 1 && nine == 1 && five == 1 & seven == 1 && two == 1 && ninetwo == 1) {
    document.getElementById("main-view").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/gray.png')";
    document.getElementById("1").onclick = null;
    document.getElementById("6").onclick = null;
    document.getElementById("9").onclick = null;
    document.getElementById("12").onclick = null;
    document.getElementById("14").onclick = null;
    document.getElementById("21").onclick = null;
    document.getElementById("34").onclick = null;
    document.onclick = null;
  } else {
    alert("You Must Find The Code To Use The Lock.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to add a secondary function after this, how would I go about that? Would I use "addEventListener" this time around? Or would there be another method?

Comment: @Equity No you can use `document.getElementById("button").onclick = newFunction;` to assign a new function, but you can also use addEventListener if you would rather do that.

Comment: @Equity You can use whatever method you want. You just have to be consistent between the way you add the listener and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind the onclick function by setting it to null instead of using `removeEventListener`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('unbind me');
  // if you want to unbind the function
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = null;
  // if you want to assign a new unction.
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = newFunction;
  
}

function newFunction() {
  console.log("hello new");
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">
  unbind me
</button>
```

You are trying to remove an eventlistener that is not present, because it is never set by `addEventListener`. You have an onclick listener that is set on the DOM, so you need to unbind that function by setting it to null.

Answer (score 0):

A call like `removeListener("click", myFunc, true);` will only remove a listener that was added using `addListener("click", myFunc, true);`. Here is an example:

```js
var flag = true;

function toggle() {
  if (flag) document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", removeImg);
  else document.getElementById("1").removeEventListener("click", removeImg);
  flag = !flag;
}

function removeImg() {
  console.log("Clicked");
}

document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

```html
<button id="1">Test</button>
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Here is a list of things you should check if it still doesn't work:

- Use the same function in the `addEventListener` as in the `removeListener` (`() => {}` is not the same as `() => {}`)
- Use the same `useCapture` value (both need to be `true` or both need to be `false`)
- Check that you are removing the listener from the correct element
- Check that the listener has only been added once to the element